# Extract the first word of a string in a SQL Server query

Tags: t-sql

What's the best way to extract the first word of a string in sql server query?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE CHARINDEX(' ', @Foo, 1)
     WHEN 0 THEN @Foo -- empty or single word
     ELSE SUBSTRING(@Foo, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @Foo, 1) - 1) -- multi-word
END
```

You could perhaps use this in a UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FirstWord] (@value varchar(max))
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CASE CHARINDEX(' ', @value, 1)
        WHEN 0 THEN @value
        ELSE SUBSTRING(@value, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @value, 1) - 1) END
END
GO -- test:
SELECT dbo.FirstWord(NULL)
SELECT dbo.FirstWord('')
SELECT dbo.FirstWord('abc')
SELECT dbo.FirstWord('abc def')
SELECT dbo.FirstWord('abc def ghi')
```

Comment: Thanks for this UDF - I noticed that 
select dbo.[FirstWord](' abc def') 
will return '' 
In most cases you probably want to return 'abc'

Comment: My words are in non-ASCII format and when i use your code the new column's values set as ????, how to solve it?

Answer (score 63):

I wanted to do something like this without making a separate function, and came up with this simple one-line approach:

```
DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(255)
SET @test = 'First Second'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@test,1,(CHARINDEX(' ',@test + ' ')-1))
```

This would return the result "First"

It's short, just not as robust, as it assumes your string doesn't start with a space. It will handle one-word inputs, multi-word inputs, and empty string inputs.

Comment: This was perfect, Thanks so much!

Comment: For someone looking to find a general example, this makes more sense than the top answer.

Comment: To handle string starting with a space just do:`SELECT SUBSTRING(LTRIM(@test),1,(CHARINDEX(' ',LTRIM(@test) + ' ')-1))`

Comment: @BenBrandt - Yours is about 26% faster, as well.  The only time yours will run into an issue is if the original string is cast as a VARCHAR(4000) or NVARCHAR(4000).  Your post also spawned some other interesting ideas.

Answer (score 8):

Enhancement of Ben Brandt's answer to compensate even if the string starts with space by applying LTRIM(). Tried to edit his answer but rejected, so I am now posting it here separately.

```
DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(255)
SET @test = 'First Second'

SELECT SUBSTRING(LTRIM(@test),1,(CHARINDEX(' ',LTRIM(@test) + ' ')-1))
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding the following before the `RETURN` statement would solve for the cases where a leading space was included in the field:

```
SET @Value = LTRIM(RTRIM(@Value))
```

Answer (score 5):

Marc's answer got me most of the way to what I needed, but I had to go with `patIndex` rather than `charIndex` because sometimes characters other than spaces mark the ends of my data's words.  Here I'm using `'%[ /-]%'` to look for space, slash, or dash.

```
Select race_id, race_description
    , Case patIndex ('%[ /-]%', LTrim (race_description))
        When 0 Then LTrim (race_description)
        Else substring (LTrim (race_description), 1, patIndex ('%[ /-]%', LTrim (race_description)) - 1)
    End race_abbreviation
from tbl_races
```

Results...

```
race_id  race_description           race_abbreviation
-------  -------------------------  -----------------
1        White                      White
2        Black or African American  Black
3        Hispanic/Latino            Hispanic
```

Caveat: this is for a small data set (US federal race reporting categories); I don't know what would happen to performance when scaled up to huge numbers.

Answer (score 5):

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(50)

SET @string = 'CUT STRING'

SELECT LEFT(@string,(PATINDEX('% %',@string)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Extract the first word from the indicated field:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(field1, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', field1)) FROM table1;
```

Extract the second and successive words from the indicated field:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(field1, CHARINDEX(' ', field1)+1, LEN (field1)-CHARINDEX(' ', field1)) FROM table1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A slight tweak to the function returns the next word from a start point in the entry

    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetWord] 
    (
        @value varchar(max)
        , @startLocation int
    ) 
    RETURNS varchar(max) 
    AS 
      BEGIN 

         SET @value = LTRIM(RTRIM(@Value))  
         SELECT @startLocation = 
                CASE 
                    WHEN @startLocation > Len(@value) THEN LEN(@value) 
                    ELSE @startLocation 
                END

            SELECT @value = 
                CASE 
                    WHEN @startLocation > 1 
                        THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(@value, LEN(@value) - @startLocation)))
                    ELSE @value
                END

            RETURN CASE CHARINDEX(' ', @value, 1) 
                    WHEN 0 THEN @value 
                    ELSE SUBSTRING(@value, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @value, 1) - 1) 
                END

     END 
    GO

    SELECT dbo.GetWord(NULL, 1) 
    SELECT dbo.GetWord('', 1) 
    SELECT dbo.GetWord('abc', 1) 
    SELECT dbo.GetWord('abc def', 4) 
    SELECT dbo.GetWord('abc def ghi', 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Select race_id, race_description
, Case patIndex ('%[ /-]%', LTrim (race_description))
    When 0 Then LTrim (race_description)
    Else substring (LTrim (race_description), 1, patIndex ('%[ /-]%', LTrim (race_description)) - 1)
End race_abbreviation
```

from tbl_races