# How do I get a string before a blank in SQL Server? ' '

Tags: sql-server

Possible inputs:

Hello World

La la, la la

Jack Bundy

I want to get into a variable the string BEFORE the first empty string ' '.

'Hello' or 'La' or 'Jack' accordingly.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707610/extract-the-first-word-of-a-string-in-a-sql-server-query

Comment: What do you want to happen when the string doesn't contain a space?

Answer (score 4):

Simplest (without dealing with my comment) is:

```
SELECT LEFT(@string, CHARINDEX(' ', @string));
```

You also need to cater for the case where the string doesn't contain a space. One way is as follows, assuming that `@string` can be at most 255 characters:

```
SELECT LEFT(@string, COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', @string), 0), 255));
```

These will leave a trailing space if a space is found. If you need to, you can get rid of that easily by wrapping the entire expression in `LTRIM()`:

```
SELECT LTRIM(LEFT(@string, COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', @string), 0), 255)));
```

Or by subtracting one from the position where the space is found:

```
SELECT LEFT(@string, COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', @string)-1, -1), 255));
```

Comment: If string length is unknown: `SELECT LEFT(@string, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', @string) - 1, 0), Len(@string)));`

Comment: @Mike how is string length "unknown"? Surely the variable or column has been defined with a maximum length.

Comment: @Mike With MAX there is still a max (no pun intended). Seems to be an edge case to me. Typically you don't want to bother performing an expensive check of the length if you don't have to. And can you show on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) a repro of this error with non-null columns?

Comment: @Mike not really fair, you changed the code in my answer. You're comparing -1 to 0; I'm not - I'm comparing -1 to -1. My code is more like this, which does not throw an error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a82bb/5 I was asking you to demonstrate a case where *my code* throws an error, not your adaptation of it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42815/discussion-between-mike-and-aaron-bertrand)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @v AS VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Hello world'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@v, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', @v))
```