# Extracting first word from a string in SQL, where the string is a single word

Tags: sql, substring, ansi-sql

I am able to extract the first word from a string, using ANSI SQL, like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name FROM 1 FOR POSITION(' ' IN name)) AS first_name
```

However, if the original string is only one word long (ie, if there is no space), it returns an empty substring.

How can the above query be adapted to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract the first word of a string in a SQL Server query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707610/extract-the-first-word-of-a-string-in-a-sql-server-query)

Comment: By the way, please specify the SQL dialect (Oracle, SQL Server, Access, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.). ANSI SQL is the general standard term for the language but differ among server types.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do it, but this works.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (i varchar(100));

INSERT INTO @tbl ( i )
VALUES  ('hello'), ('hello space here');

SELECT *, 
    SUBSTRING(i, 0, CASE CHARINDEX(' ', i)
        WHEN 0 THEN LEN(i) + 1
        ELSE CHARINDEX(' ', i)
    END)
FROM @tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply but messy solution - add a space on the end:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING((name || ' ') FROM 1 FOR POSITION(' ' IN (name || ' '))) AS first_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a conditional if statement.

For a MySQL/SQL Server answer:

```
SELECT IF(INSTR(name, ' ') >0, LEFT(name, INSTR(name, ' ') - 1), name) AS firstname
```

For Oracle:

```
SELECT IF(INSTRB(name, ' ', 1, 1) >0, SUBSTR(name, 1, INSTRB(name, ' ', 1, 1) - 1), name) AS firstname
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer the Regexp query for this, but below query also works.
You basically append a space at the end of the string and search for the position of the space using `INSTR`.

ORACLE:

```
select substr(Var1, 0,INSTR(Var1||' ',' ')) from table-name;
```

Replace `Var1` with the column-name or string you are evaluating.

Answer (score 0):

**Put Column Name in place of @foo**

```
DECLARE @Foo VARCHAR(50) = 'One Two Three'

SELECT 
CASE
--For One Word
WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', @Foo, 1) = 0 THEN @Foo

--For multi word
ELSE SUBSTRING(@Foo, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @Foo, 1) - 1)

END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(50) = 'One Two Three'
SELECT SUBSTRING(LTRIM(@test),1,(CHARINDEX(' ',LTRIM(@test) + ' ')-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to get the first word of a string.initcap
will get you the first letter capital.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(column_1, 1, INSTR(column_1, ' ', 1,1) ) FROM table_name WHERE  column_1= initcap('your string');
```